# ServiceManagement API exception calling Azure cmdlets from powershell

Tags: azure, powershell-3.0, azure-powershell

I'm trying to create VM using Azure Powershell. So i've imported Azure pulish settings file from portal. When i run any of the commands like "Get-AzureLocation" or "Get-AzureVM" etc i'm getting below exception. Need any help or suggestions.

PS C:\Users\YVM> Get-AzureVM

Get-AzureVM : "An exception occurred when calling the ServiceManagement API. HTTP Status Code: 407. Service Error Code: . Message: . Operation Tracking ID: ."
At line:1 char:1 + Get-AzureVM + ~~~~~~~~~~~    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureVM], ServiceManagementClientException    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.ServiceManagement.IaaS.GetAzureVMCommand

Comment: Can you check if you're not behind a proxy server?

Answer (score 1):

Can you run the command with the -Debug option, or using $DebugPreference=Continue.  This should provide a debug trace with some more details about where the call is failing and the exact message you're getting back.